# Why are there account aliases?

Tags: user-account, alias

I don't understand why when I go to /Users/Me, I find an alias of "me", and then another inside, and then again.
Can this alter the performances? Can I trash them?
And moreover, what are they doing here?

Answer (score 1):

There's one alias which you created. Opening the alias navigates to the folder, and the folder has the alias in it. Thus, there's just one alias. Delete it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The logic of the mirror, of course... :-) !